# Search in TCL expect using variable name doesn't fetch answer

Tags: tcl, expect

I doing telnet via an Expect script, and send some command and expect the the below.

```
expect -re {02 : (.*?)\s}
set output $expect_out(1,string)
puts "output is $output"
```

> => output is 3  (this is the right answer)

```
set tests "02 : "

expect -re {"$tests"(.*?)\s}
set output $expect_out(1,string)
puts "output is $output"
```

> => output is 2 (some other value, this value is the older value present in $expect_out(1,string) that was used to search other text)

Can I save the text to be searched in a variable and pass to `expect-re {....}` ?
I want the text to be searched in a variable, and then pass that variable in `expect`..

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
expect -re {($tests)(.*?)\s}
```

Comment: Your instinct is correct and I expect you to get an answer… but ___BEWARE!!!___ Care must be taken when building REs by pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is that the variable is not being expanded within the braces. Try this instead:

```
expect -re "${tests}(.*?)\\s"
```

Compare the difference between:

```
puts {"$tests"(.*?)\s}
# Output: "$tests"(.*?)\s
puts "${tests}(.*?)\\s"
# Output: 02 : (.*?)\s
```

The braces prevent substitution of the value of `$tests` and instead just puts a literal `$tests` as the regular expression. The quotes ensure that you actually get the value of `$tests`. I have added additional braces (to make it `${tests}`) because otherwise the parens are treated as part of the variable expansion.

Comment: There are peculiarities about `expect` that can make this harder (it does “clever” stuff in some circumstances), but it ought to work as you say here.

Answer (score 1):

@user108471 has the answer for you. Here are a couple of alternatives to build the regex:

```
set tests "02 : "
set suffix {(.*?)\s}
set regex [string cat $tests $suffix]

expect -re $regex
set output $expect_out(1,string)
puts "output is $output"
```

This requires your expect be built on Tcl 8.6.2 (which introduced the `string cat` command): verify with `expect -c 'puts [info patchlevel]'`

Also, you appear to want non-whitespace characters with `(.*?)\s`. This can also be accomplished with `\S*` -- that's a bit simpler:

```
set regex "${tests}(\\S*)"
```

Comment: I am yet to test this.. Thank you very much